# Next.js 13: gray-matter is not working in Next 13

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

After migrating an app from Next 12 to Next 13, I found that **gray-matter** broke down. The same code worked fine, in the previous version of Next.js, i.e., Next 12.

Prior to migration, the following code worked fine:

```js
const source = fs.readFileSync(sourcePath);

const {content, data} = matter(source);
```

It returned the desired result.

After migration, the above code returns `undefined`, in both client side as well as server side.

I tried everything and nothing seems to work. Is there any alternative to gray-matter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should review the documentation when upgrading a major version to look for breaking changes. Additionally, you should check for conflicting package versions in your package-lock.json

Comment: Gray matter seems to be working in the client side. But on running it on the server side, it seems to be broken. Any solutions?